# Equivalent to java | operator in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

If i want to return two Gravity values at same time in java, I do this:

```
private int rightCenterVertical() {
   return Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
}
```

How can that be transformed to kotlin code?

To be honest, I don't know how it's called the "`|`" operator from java that is used to mix two values and return both of them.

Comment: It's the bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In kotlin it is just called `or` so your code would look like this:

```kotlin
fun rightCenterVertical(): Int {
   return Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
}
```

Comment: May be worth adding that, unlike Java, it's implemented as an infix function in the standard library, not an operator in the language syntax. Kotlin docs for it are [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/or.html).

Comment: That is correct, but in this case it is the bitwise or operator presumably between two Ints. Kotlin docs for the bitwise or are [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/or.html).

Comment: (Whoops, yes, you're right of course!)  Anyway, feel free to add that into your answer.